# check if all text inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if all text inputs with class 'textinput' are empty, but it only seems to check if the first input is empty or not, I can't figure out why. can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    var allEmpty;
       $('.textinput').each(function(){
     if(!$('.textinput').val()){
       allEmpty = true;
     }
   });
     if (allEmpty == true){
        alert('all empty');   
     }
});
```

Comment: thanks all for the explanations and the code. It is much clearer to me now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong; you are setting allEmpty = true for each single item.
You have to invert your logic:

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    var almostOneNotEmpty = false;
       $('.textinput').each(function(){
     if($(this).val()){
       almostOneNotEmpty = true;
     }
   });
     if (!almostOneNotEmpty == true){
        alert('all empty');   
     }
});
```

Comment: thanks for explaining it to me I think I get it now. Your code works well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Find all `.textinput` that are not empty, and check the selector length. If none exist, they are all empty :

```
$('#check').on('click', function(){
    var allEmpty = ! $('.textinput').filter(function() {
                       return $.trim( this.value ) != "";
                   }).length;

    if (allEmpty) alert('all empty');   
});
```

or

```
if ( ! $('.textinput[value !=""]').length ) alert('all empty');
```

Comment: Your `$('.textinput[value!=""]').length` solution is pretty elegant.

Comment: Your second solution says, if any have a value, alert that they are empty.

Comment: @Marc - actually, it finds elements that has a value, and if any of those exist, i.e. the selector has length, all elements are not empty!

Comment: @adeneo, exactly. if there are any, alert the text `all empty`. Edit: it's all better now ;)

Comment: @Marc - you're right! Was focusing on the selector, and got the conditional bacwards, even on the first one! Added a "not", Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try checking against the opposite logic. If any of the values are set, then they're `not` all empty.

Also, you want to make use of `$(this)` when you're within the context of the `.each()` function. Otherwise, calling `$('.textinput')` will re-select those elements again rather than working on the current one.

Adding [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) ensures that whitespace is not counted as an actual value, but you can remove this if you want to count whitespace as a value.

```
$('#check').click(function() {
  var allEmpty = true;
  $('.textinput').each(function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val())) {
      allEmpty = false;
    }
  });
  if (allEmpty == true){
    alert('all empty');   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the element that is selected by the each method by using "this".

```
$('#check').click(function () {
    var allEmpty;
    $('.textinput').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            allEmpty = true;
        }
    });
    if (allEmpty == true) {
        alert('all empty');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be your condition >>

```
if(!$('.textinput').val()){

}else {
  allEmpty = true;
}
```

Comment: so.. if the first one has no value, then they all don't?

Comment: no, this is the condition statement, it still needs to be put in the `.each()`

Answer (score 1):

This simple check will tell you if they are all empty:

```
var isEmpty = !$('.textinput').map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join('');
```

This will give you boolean `true` if all the fields are blank.